# Conceptual doubts with cross validation and train / test split?

Tags: machine-learning, cross-validation, python, scikit-learn

I have doubts regarding cross validation and train / test split. I understand the following... please correct me if I am wrong.

If I use train and test split, with the following code, I will be able to:

```
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, train_size=0.7)
clf.fit(X_train, y_train)

y_pred = clf.predict(X_train)
metrics.accuracy_score(y_train, y_pred)

y_pred = clf.predict(X_test)
metrics.accuracy_score(y_test, y_pred)
```

1 - Get a model

2 - Obtain a score of  the model on the same data with which he was trained

3 - Get a score of the model, testing it with data that he has never seen

Now my doubt with cross validation is ... it is useful to use cross validation after the split, and apply this cross validation only on the train data?

I understand that I do not get any model

If what I get are only scores, so that they are useful to me?
 
Do they best represent the train score, or does it represent the test score better?

```
scores = cross_val_score(clf, X_train, y_train, cv=10)
np.mean(scores)
```

Thank you very much for the help

Comment: You should be using cross-validation solely on the training data (i.e. after the split) to tune your model (e.g. to choose the hyperparameters or even to choose the type of model).  It may give you an estimate for the out-of-sample error, but in some cases not a particularly good one if there is overfitting